# Combining switch statement with onMouseOver to display text & image (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, switch-statement, onmouseover

I'm new to javascript and am looking to add what I think is a relatively simple function to my website (still being worked on and not yet hosted).  I've been known to be horribly wrong when it comes to what I think should be simple, though. :)

I have effects I'm adding to display the image, but I can apply those now, so that's not currently a problem.

The reference materials I have don't go into this explicitly, so please pardon the fact that I'm probably butchering some of the code (especially that in the switching statement).

I would like the action of hovering (or onMouseOver) of a link (on the same page, but not near the divs) to display an image in a div and a text box in a separate div below the image.  Any help in straightening this out would be appreciated.

I have four links with the following IDs:

```
 #btn_a;
 #btn_b;
 #btn_c;
 #btn_d;
```

I have four images with the following IDs:

```
#img_a = "img/ima.jpg";
#img_b = "img/imb.jpg";
#img_c = "img/imc.jpg";
#img_d = "img/imd.jpg";
```

I have four text boxes with the following IDs:

```
#txt_a = "Aaaa";
#txt_b = "Bbbb";
#txt_c = "Cccc";
#txt_d = "Dddd";
```

I have assigned two local variables:

```
var varTX; // text
var varIM; // images
```

The script I have is as follows:

THE JAVASCRIPT

```
function textBox(varTX){
var varTX=new text();
switch (varTX)
{
case 1: btn_a.onMouseOver: var varTX = "txt_a";
break;
case 2: btn_b.onMouseOver: var varTX = "txt_b";
break;
case 3: btn_c.onMouseOver: var varTX = "txt_c";
break;
case 4: btn_d.onMouseOver: var varTX = "txt_d";
break;
default: varTX = "no text";
}

function textBox(varIM){
var varIM=new image();
switch (varIM)
{
case 1: btn_a.onMouseOver: var varIM = "img_a";
break;
case 2: btn_b.onMouseOver: var varIM = "img_b";
break;
case 3: btn_c.onMouseOver: var varIM = "img_c";
break;
case 4: btn_d.onMouseOver: var varIM = "img_d";
break;
default: varIM = "no image";
}
```

THE HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="target"><ul>
<li><a href="#" id="btn_a">test_a</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="btn_b">test_b</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="btn_c">test_c</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="btn_d">test_d</a></li>
</ul></div>

<div class="images">
<a href="#">
<img src=<script>textBox("varIM")</script>
width="100%" height="30%" class="latest_img" /></a>
</div>

<div class="images">
<a href="#">
<h3 width="100%" height="30%" class="latest_img" />
<script>textBox("varTX")</script>
</h3></span></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When posting code blocks to this site, begin each line with four spaces. That way it will know that it's code and format it correctly. For inline code, surround it in backticks (`).

Comment: I see no jQuery in your code. Are you actually using jQuery?

Comment: @FishBasketGordo, thanks for fixing!  I wasn't getting results when I used spaces.

Comment: @Joseph, I'm using jQuery for some other things on the page, forgot I abbreviated this section so much.

Comment: you have the h3 tag closed twice

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss The </span> tag?  It was used in a prior iteration.  It's been removed.  Thanks!

Comment: NO, the H3 TAG is closed twice, once with the ` />` at the end of the begin tag, and another with the `</h3>` the close `</span>` tag is now an orphan. AND you really should get those script tags OUT of the markup - those in the img are totally invalid as coded.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong here.

1) This is invalid. You can't inline a `<script>` tag.

```
<img src=<script>textBox("varIM")</script>
width="100%" height="30%" class="latest_img" />`
```

2) You can't switch on two values in a switch statement, only one. This is wrong:

```
switch (varTX, varIM)
```

3) You can't have two elements with the same ID. That's invalid markup.

```
<div id="images">
...
<div id="images">
```

Fix these problems and post another question if you're still having trouble.

Comment: I would like to add that `var varTX = "txt_d" varIM = "img_d";` is invalid too (need a `,`), as well as `case 2: btn_b.onMouseOver:` (need `case` twice) and it's `Image` not `image`.

Comment: I've updated the code to solve 2) and 3).  How can I "drop in" the variable to change the image src to solve 1)?

Comment: @Scott Please start a new question with your amended code. We like to keep it one question per post on this site. Thanks.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo I don't understand.  It's still the same question.

Comment: I reverted your updates. If you iteratively edit the code example in your question with each suggestion, this post won't be much good to anyone else. That's why I'm saying to fix the problems you already know about and post another question with the next problem you come against. SO questions shouldn't be used like a workbench for fixing your code. They're more like a snapshot of a problem with the solutions to that problem in the answers section.

Comment: @pimvdb Not sure where you mean for me to place the comma and second "case". For image vs. Image, do you mean for me to change var varIM=new image(); to var varIM=new Image(); ?

Comment: @Scott: You'd need `var varTX = "txt_d", varIM = "img_d";` and `case 1: case btn_a.onMouseOver: var varTX = "txt_a"; break;`. You're correct about `Image`.

Answer (score 0):

As Others have pointed out there are a few issues with the code.  I've tried to get the basic functionality working and clean up the markup a little.  You can accomplish this with either javascript or jQuery

> ### Method One (javascript)
>
> #### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dhLG/2)

---

This is a pure js way to do it.  It's very incomplete so you'll have to work on it but this should give you a general idea of what you should be doing.

```
var links = document.getElementById("target").getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
    links[i].onclick = function(){replaceImage(this); return false;}
}

function replaceImage(obj)
{
    document.getElementById("imagesI").src = "img_" + obj.id.split("_")[1];
    document.getElementById("imagesT").innerText = "txt_" + obj.id.split("_")[1];
}
```

> ### Method Two (jQuery)
>
> #### [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/4dhLG/1)

---

This is a jQuery way of doing it.  Also incomplete, this will need work.

```
$("#target a").click(function(){
    $("#imagesI").attr("src", "img_" + this.id.split("_")[1]);
    $("#imagesT").html("txt_" + this.id.split("_")[1]);
    return false;
})
```

If you get stuck or need help along the way don't hesitate to ask us for help. :)

Comment: That looks compeltely foreign to me. It may take a lot of help :)

Comment: @Scott and that's ok :P that's what we're here for :)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this will get you started, tossing out the switch and use the jquery:

```
<div id="target"><ul> <li><a href="#" id="btn_a">test_a</a></li> <li><a href="#" id="btn_b">test_b</a></li> <li><a href="#" id="btn_c">test_c</a></li> <li><a href="#" id="btn_d">test_d</a></li> </ul></div>  <div id="images"> <a href="#"> <img src='' width="100%" height="20px" class="latest_img" /></a> </div>  <div id="imagestext"> <a href="#"> <h3 width="100%" height="30%" class="latest_img" >  </h3></span></a> </div> <div id='meme'>empty</div>
```

and the jquery:

```
$('#target').find('a').hover(function() {
    var iamover = $(this).text();
    $('#meme').text(iamover);
    $('#images').find('img', function() {
        $(this).attr('alt', iamover);
        $(this).attr('src', 'myimage.jpg');
    });
    $('#imagestext').find('a>h3', function() {
        $(this).text(iamover);
    });
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/zah9X/

Comment: I'm playing with this and it looks interesting.  I'm not getting my images to load, however so I'm going to see what I changed.

Comment: I think I found out why images aren't loading: img src=''.  Also, I would need the text test_a, etc. to display a different wording than the buttons have.